# Format Duration to show just Minutes, Seconds and Milliseconds? - Flutter/Dart

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to formate video length from duration to standard text format

```
Duration(hours: 1, minutes: 12, seconds: 55);
```

Result i Want `1:12:55`

Answer (score 0):

You can use [intl](https://pub.dev/packages/intl) package, which provides `DateFormat` utility class.

Then in code use it like:

```
const duration = Duration(hours: 1, minutes: 12, seconds: 55);
final df = DateFormat("HH:mm:ss");
final formattedString = df.format(DateTime.fromMillisecondsSinceEpoch(duration.inMilliseconds, isUtc: true));
```

Answer (score -1):

There're many nice libraries from pub.dev, they support the VIDEO trim function.  If you got questions from those libraries, you need to mention more clearly what you used and what you tried already.

[video_editor 1.4.3](https://pub.dev/packages/video_editor)

[video_trimmer 1.1.3](https://pub.dev/packages/video_trimmer)

[image]